# Analog to WebDriverWait just for WebElement

Tags: java, selenium

I have found element using next construction.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement wsearchlist = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("")));
```

after that i want to look for internal element

```
By by = new By.ByLinkText(testName);
wsearch = wsearchlist.findElement(by);
```

This behavior not trying to wait for availability of internal element. I want to use same or something same to "wait" object to search one element it the other one. How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`elementToBeClickable`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) expect `By` object as well as `WebElement` object as input, you wait until this element visible and clickable as below :-

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(wsearch));
```

If you want to wait for nested element try using [`presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) which expect `WebElement` and `By` object to wait until presence of element on `DOM` in the context of `WebElement` as below :-

```
By by = new By.ByLinkText(testName);
WebElement wsearch = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy(wsearchlist, by));
```

Hope it helps...:)

Comment: I use this cunstruction to be able to get element at all. in case in is JS added content so should wait for it. I have no element just By..

Comment: @YevgenKulik Then you should use `presenceOfNestedElementLocatedBy`.. see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to create a custom Function to assist with this process using your *WebDriverWait* reference.

**Provided code sample is untested**

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        final String testName = "";
        final WebElement wsearchlist = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("")));
        WebElement wsearch = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver input) {
                By by = new By.ByLinkText(testName);
                WebElement search = null;
                search = wsearchlist.findElement(by);
                return search;
            }}); 

        //Continue on.
```

if the `wait.ignoring` call doesn't work on the `NoSuchElementException`, then add a try/catch block to the *Function*

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        //wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        final String testName = "";
        final WebElement wsearchlist = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("")));
        WebElement wsearch = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver input) {
                By by = new By.ByLinkText(testName);
                WebElement search = null;
                try {
                    search = wsearchlist.findElement(by);
                } catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
                    nsee.printStackTrace();
                    //FIXME:  LOG THIS
                }
                return search;
            }}); 

        //Continue on.
```